# AWK : Field Separator as Double Pipes or more

Tags: unix, awk

My data:

```
-1||"A|AA"||aaa@ymail
-10||"B ||B|ttB||b|| bb@ymail
-7||C||c
```

I want to exchange the double pipe delimiters `||` with a comma `,` like this:

```
awk -F'||' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1} 1' 2.txt
```

but the output remains the same. 
The reverse case (comma delimiter to double pipe), however, works:

```
awk -F"," -v OFS="||" '{$1=$1} 1' 1.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the close quote on line 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe symbol:

```
awk -F '[|][|]' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}1'
```

Comment: +1: Hopefully this would compensate though getting a downvote for a good working solution is frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape metacharacters like `|` or use them in character class so that they are considered literals. They are considered logical `OR` notation without escapes. Try this:

```
$ awk -F'[|][|]' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1} 1' data
-1,"A|AA",aaa@ymail
-10,"B ,B|ttB,b, bb@ymail
-7,C,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to do this :

```
awk -F '[|][|]' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}1' # as suggested by accepted anwer
awk -F '[|]{2}' # my favorite as it is easier to extend this solution to more than two pipes
awk -F '\\|\\|' -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}1' # another way to escape
awk -F "\\\|\\\|" -v OFS="," '{$1=$1}1' # see https://superuser.com/a/1249834
```

Comment: `awk '(NF = NF)_' FS='[|][|]' OFS=','`